# Rolling grouped cumulative sum

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to create a rolling grouped cumulative sum. I can get the result via iteration, but wanted to see if there was a more intelligent way.

Here's what the source data looks like:

```
Per C   V
1   c   3
1   a   4
1   c   1
2   a   6
2   b   5
3   j   7
4   x   6
4   x   5
4   a   9
5   a   2
6   c   3
6   k   6
```

Here is the desired result:

```
Per C   V
1   c   4
1   a   4
2   c   4
2   a   10
2   b   5
3   c   4
3   a   10
3   b   5
3   j   7
4   c   4
4   a   19
4   b   5
4   j   7
4   x   11
5   c   4
5   a   21
5   b   5
5   j   7
5   x   11
6   c   7
6   a   21
6   b   5
6   j   7
6   x   11
6   k   6
```

Comment: What's the group key and can you explain your logic briefly?

Comment: The group key would be both Per (Period) and C (Code). It is important to 'carry over' all prior groupings and sums. The logic is based on a moving distribution. For every period of time, how much of column V was accumulated over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting problem. Try below to see if it works for you.

```
(
    pd.concat([df.loc[df.Per<=i][['C','V']].assign(Per=i) for i in df.Per.unique()])
    .groupby(by=['Per','C'])
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
)

Out[197]: 
    Per  C   V
0     1  a   4
1     1  c   4
2     2  a  10
3     2  b   5
4     2  c   4
5     3  a  10
6     3  b   5
7     3  c   4
8     3  j   7
9     4  a  19
10    4  b   5
11    4  c   4
12    4  j   7
13    4  x  11
14    5  a  21
15    5  b   5
16    5  c   4
17    5  j   7
18    5  x  11
19    6  a  21
20    6  b   5
21    6  c   7
22    6  j   7
23    6  k   6
24    6  x  11
```

Comment: Impressive. The use of concat by expanding the original data with an inclusive period assignment works very well. Thx

Answer (score 3):

You could use `pivot_table/cumsum`:

```
(df.pivot_table(index='Per', columns='C', values='V', aggfunc='sum')
   .fillna(0) 
   .cumsum(axis=0)
   .replace(0, np.nan)
   .stack().reset_index())
```

yields

```
    Per  C     0
0     1  a   4.0
1     1  c   4.0
2     2  a  10.0
3     2  b   5.0
4     2  c   4.0
5     3  a  10.0
6     3  b   5.0
7     3  c   4.0
8     3  j   7.0
9     4  a  19.0
10    4  b   5.0
11    4  c   4.0
12    4  j   7.0
13    4  x  11.0
14    5  a  21.0
15    5  b   5.0
16    5  c   4.0
17    5  j   7.0
18    5  x  11.0
19    6  a  21.0
20    6  b   5.0
21    6  c   7.0
22    6  j   7.0
23    6  k   6.0
24    6  x  11.0
```

---

On the plus side, I think the `pivot_table/cumsum` approach helps convey the meaning of the calculation pretty well. Given the pivot_table, the calculation is essentially a cumulative sum down each column:

```
In [131]: df.pivot_table(index='Per', columns='C', values='V', aggfunc='sum')
Out[131]: 
C      a    b    c    j    k     x
Per                               
1    4.0  NaN  4.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
2    6.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
3    NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0  NaN   NaN
4    9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  11.0
5    2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
6    NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  6.0   NaN
```

On the negative side, the need to fuss with 0's and NaNs is not ideal. We need 0's for the cumsum, but we need NaNs to make unwanted rows to disappear when the DataFrame is stacked.

The `pivot_table/cumsum` approach also offers a considerable speed advantage over `using_concat`, but [piRSquared's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49097572/190597) is the fastest. On a 1000-row `df`:

```
In [169]: %timeit using_reindex2(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.86 ms per loop

In [152]: %timeit using_reindex(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.36 ms per loop

In [80]: %timeit using_pivot(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.58 ms per loop

In [79]: %timeit using_concat(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 84 ms per loop
```

---

Here is the setup I used for the benchmark:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def using_pivot(df):
    return (df.pivot_table(index='P', columns='C', values='V', aggfunc='sum')
             .fillna(0)
             .cumsum(axis=0)
             .replace(0, np.nan)
             .stack().reset_index())

def using_reindex(df):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/49097572/190597 (piRSquared)
    """
    s = df.set_index(['P', 'C']).V.sum(level=[0, 1])

    return s.reindex(
        pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels, names=s.index.names),
        fill_value=0
    ).groupby('C').cumsum().loc[lambda x: x > 0].reset_index()

def using_reindex2(df):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/49097572/190597 (piRSquared)
    with first line changed
    """
    s = df.groupby(['P', 'C'])['V'].sum()
    return s.reindex(
        pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels, names=s.index.names),
        fill_value=0
    ).groupby('C').cumsum().loc[lambda x: x > 0].reset_index()

def using_concat(df):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/49095139/190597 (Allen)
    """
    return (pd.concat([df.loc[df.P<=i][['C','V']].assign(P=i) 
                       for i in df.P.unique()])
              .groupby(by=['P','C'])
              .sum()
              .reset_index())

def make(nrows):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50, size=(nrows,3)), columns=list('PCV'))
    return df

df = make(1000)
```

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, I asked about summing only a single column and this solution addresses it quite well. The reality is I need to sum two columns and I'm not sure that can be done using pivot. Thoughts?

Comment: The `values` parameter passed to `pivot_table` can be a list of columns: `df.pivot_table(index='P', columns='C', values=['V','W'], aggfunc='sum')`. The rest of the computation can stay the same.

Comment: `pivot_table` has a `fill_value` parameter

Comment: @piRSquared: Ah yes. Thanks very much for the improvement.

Comment: @piRSquared: using `fill_value` instead of `fillna` slowed down the benchmark result considerably, so I'm reverting to `fillna`. In any case, I think your solution is faster. (A modified version of your solution (`using_reindex2`, above) may be even faster still.)

Comment: @unutbu interesting. I wouldn’t have guessed a loss in performance from filling the value within pivot table. I like your improvement on reindex.

Comment: @piRSquared: Yes, I found that surprising too. It turns out the difference in speed is due to [`downcast='infer'`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L116). This is done automatically when using `fill_value`, but must be added optionally if you call `fillna` yourself. If I changed `.fillna(0)` to `.fillna(0, downcast='infer')` I get the same amount of slow-down as when I tried `fill_value=0`.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the index to be `'Per'` and `'C'`, you can first accumulate over those index levels.  Then I decided to reindex the resulting series by the the product of the index levels in order to get all possibilities while filling in new indices with zero.

After this, I use `groupby`, `cumsum`, and remove zeros.

```
s = df.set_index(['Per', 'C']).V.sum(level=[0, 1])

s.reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels, names=s.index.names),
    fill_value=0
).groupby('C').cumsum().loc[lambda x: x > 0].reset_index()

    Per  C   V
0     1  a   4
1     1  c   4
2     2  a  10
3     2  b   5
4     2  c   4
5     3  a  10
6     3  b   5
7     3  c   4
8     3  j   7
9     4  a  19
10    4  b   5
11    4  c   4
12    4  j   7
13    4  x  11
14    5  a  21
15    5  b   5
16    5  c   4
17    5  j   7
18    5  x  11
19    6  a  21
20    6  b   5
21    6  c   7
22    6  j   7
23    6  k   6
24    6  x  11
```