# Python Pandas Countif

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I like to build the counting tool.

I used to use the `COUNTIF` function in excel `=COUNTIF($L$2:$L$3850,"AAA")`. but, I am not sure there is similar function in python pandas.

This is my dataframe

```
#        2015  2016  2017
#  0      AAA   AA    AA
#  1      AA    AA    A
#  2      AA    A     A
```

I want to count this dataframe like this:

```
#        2015  2016  2017
#  AAA    1     0     0
#  AA     2     2     1
#  A      0     1     2
```

How can I start the code? any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `value_counts`

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[203]: 
     2015  2016  2017
A       0     1     2
AA      2     2     1
AAA     1     0     0
```

Comment: Also: `df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0, downcast='infer')`

Comment: @piRSquared wow , never heard of `downcast`, great thank you sir

Comment: You are welcome (-: But be aware of potential performance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094885/rolling-grouped-cumulative-sum/49095493?noredirect=1#comment85205072_49095493

Comment: @JakeHan yw~ :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using `cross_tab`

```
df.stack().pipe(lambda s: pd.crosstab(s, s.index.get_level_values(1)))

col_0  2015  2016  2017
row_0                  
A         0     1     2
AA        2     2     1
AAA       1     0     0
```

---

With `get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df.values.ravel()).T.dot(
    pd.get_dummies(df.columns.repeat(len(df)))
)

     2015  2016  2017
A       0     1     2
AA      2     2     1
AAA     1     0     0
```